# How to convert HttpStatus code to int in Java?

Tags: java, spring, http-status-codes

I am using RestTemplate `postForEntity` method to `POST` to an endpoint. If `POST` is success, the `statusCode variable` should change its value to status code of `201`, but I am having difficulty converting HttpStatus to int in Java. I am getting error `Cannot cast from HttpStatus to int`  I could not get any solutions regarding this. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is my code

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

    public int postJson(Set<String> data) {
        int statusCode;
        try {

            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,new HttpEntity<>(request, getHttpHeaders()), String.class);

            statusCode = (int) result.getStatusCode();   

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("No Post", e);
        }
        return statusCode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or,

you just use `getStatusCodeValue()` for short cut.

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

public int postJson(Set<String> data) {
    int statusCode;
    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,new HttpEntity<>(request, getHttpHeaders()), String.class);
        statusCode = result.getStatusCodeValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("No Post", e);
    }
    return statusCode;
}
```

Comment: Use More succinct and short 

   `HttpStatus.OK.value();`

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Framework returns an Enum with the `HttpStatus`:

```
public class ResponseEntity<T> extends HttpEntity<T> {

    /**
     * Return the HTTP status code of the response.
     * @return the HTTP status as an HttpStatus enum entry
     */
    public HttpStatus getStatusCode() {
        if (this.status instanceof HttpStatus) {
            return (HttpStatus) this.status;
        }
        else {
            return HttpStatus.valueOf((Integer) this.status);
        }
    }
}
```

And the enum is defined as the following:

```
public enum HttpStatus {

    // 1xx Informational

    /**
     * {@code 100 Continue}.
     * @see <a href="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.2.1">HTTP/1.1: Semantics and Content, section 6.2.1</a>
     */
    CONTINUE(100, "Continue"),

   // ...
}
```

So you can obtain the status as an `int` as the following:

```
int statusCode = result.getStatusCode().value();
```

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is test ```postForEntity``` method, if it is success then status code should change to success which is ```201```

Comment: that does not reflect the question you asked